# AWS Cognito Authentication Working on Postman but not on Angular web app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I configured Authentication for all the APIs which are deployed on the server. Now when I hit the endpoint by Postman. It is working fine, accepting jwt token to access other APIs but when I am hitting the same API with Angular app then even after passing Authentication in headers it is saying Unauthorized error.

Please help me!

The code is as follows:

```
createHeader() {
    return (this.header = new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: localStorage.getItem("token")
    }));
  }
```

Comment: Please share your angular code where you are making this API call.

Comment: I have added the code in the post.

Comment: Did you send id_token or access_token from postman

Comment: I sent id_token from the postman. Same I tried in angular but every time it is showing unauthorize error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was related to cors which was not allowing the angular app to hit any lambda API through amazon gateway.

Solution: There are two ways which are as follows:

1) You can run the below command on the terminal which will let you hit the API gateway API:

```
google-chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_tmp"
```

2) The second way involves editing your serverless.yml file:

```
- http:
      path: permission/
      method: any
      cors: true
```

You have to declare cors as true. Now the question is what it will do? The answer is as follows:

The serverless framework allows you to configure CORS in detail. The cors: true is a shortcut for the following configuration.

```
cors:
origins:
    - '*'
headers:
    - Content-Type
    - X-Amz-Date
    - Authorization
    - X-Api-Key
    - X-Amz-Security-Token
allowCredentials: false
```

Comment: I am not using serverless, but I am still being blocked by CORS, even though my API gateway is configured to allow all domains from a CORS perspective. I can make the call  just fine in Postman but I can't even make it to the authorizer lambda from angular.

Comment: I think you have to enable cors.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that Postman is adding the "Bearer " prefix to the auth token which is not happening in your code above.

try:

```
  createHeader() {
    return (this.header = new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
    }));
  }
```

Comment: Hey! I tried adding Bearer but still it is not authenticating the request.